# Can I perform a dot product between binary sparse matrices using just the numpy `indptr` and `indices` arrays?

Tags: numpy, sparse-matrix, cosine-similarity, dot-product

I'd like to perform the dot product between two sparse matrices without using `scipy.sparse`. This should only use the `csrmat.indices` and `csrmat.indtpr` arrays, so it would be performed in `numpy` only. The reason for this is I would like to perform the dot product in `PyKeOps` on the GPU, which does not support sparse matrices, but will happily operate on numpy-style arrays.

An example of a sparse matrix with binary values. This type of matrix might arise from TF-IDF featurization:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import rand
from scipy import sparse

#how many instances?
n = 100
#how many dimensions?
d = 5000
#construct a binary sparse array
x = rand(n, d, density=0.05, format='csr')
x.data[:] = 1
```

Now, it's trivial to perform the dot product with itself, resulting in a dense output counting the number of shared elements between each row in the sparse matrix. This is the first step in calculating Jaccard distance or Cosine similarity:

```
intersections = x.dot(x.T).toarray()
intersections
>>>>>
array([[265.,  13.,  10., ...,  16.,  20.,  15.],
       [ 13., 246.,  14., ...,  11.,   9.,  12.],
       [ 10.,  14., 254., ...,  11.,  15.,  14.],
       ...,
       [ 16.,  11.,  11., ..., 245.,   7.,  19.],
       [ 20.,   9.,  15., ...,   7., 272.,  15.],
       [ 15.,  12.,  14., ...,  19.,  15., 262.]])
```

Is there a vectorized way to do this operation using the `x.indices` and `x.indptr` arrays? A slow and bad example might be:

```
indices = x.indices
indptr = x.indptr
results = np.zeros([n,n])

for countj, j in enumerate(range(indptr[:-1].shape[0])):
  startj = indptr[j]
  endj = indptr[j+1]
  itemsj = indices[startj:endj]

  for countk, k in enumerate(range(indptr[:-1].shape[0])):
    startk = indptr[k]
    endk = indptr[k+1]
    itemsk = indices[startk:endk]

    overlap = np.isin(itemsk, itemsj)
    results[countj, countk] = overlap.sum()

results
>>>>
array([[265.,  13.,  10., ...,  16.,  20.,  15.],
       [ 13., 246.,  14., ...,  11.,   9.,  12.],
       [ 10.,  14., 254., ...,  11.,  15.,  14.],
       ...,
       [ 16.,  11.,  11., ..., 245.,   7.,  19.],
       [ 20.,   9.,  15., ...,   7., 272.,  15.],
       [ 15.,  12.,  14., ...,  19.,  15., 262.]])
```

However this example won't run in PyKeOps since it doesn't use broadcasting (i.e. its not vectorized).

Thanks!

Comment: A standard 1990's math paper is referenced in the comments of the `scipy` `csr` matrix multiplication method.  It's a 2 pass method using `cython` code.

Comment: thanks @hpaulj, if you look at the source code for the `csr_matmat`, it uses a lot of control flow (i.e. if/else), which runs fine in compiled code but I think would become extremely slow if reimplemented using the python interpreter. If you can see a way to perform those same operations using vectorized numpy I'd love to see it! thanks. Link: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2eeed791ce100fd2bf127967ec41759ad3b4598c/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h#L562

Comment: It's possible, with the caveat that you still have to loop through n and performance will be trash. You'd be better served by either chunking it to dense if it's not very sparse or using SYRK from mkl or something in the cpu if it's highly sparse and d >> n

Comment: cheers @CJR , unfortunately real use case is d~64,000 and n~100,000, hence the desire for GPU-acceleration (i.e. pykeops).

Comment: @lewiso1 How sparse? I would expect a high-sparsity matrix at that size to be much better on the CPU with something like `mkl_sparse_syrk` because you could keep it sparse afterwards (or cut it straight into a dense matrix with `mkl_sparse_d_syrkd`), and your performance trying to manage a 30gb array into and out of GPU memory will be terrible anyway

Comment: Very sparse - ~50 bits per row, so 7.8e-9. Main reason to use `PyKeOps` is that the dense output matrix won't fit in memory - 100k * 100k entries - and `PyKeOps` can operate on this matrix on-the-fly without evaluating the entire thing and storing in memory. I'll have a crack with `mkl_sparse_d_syrkd` and report back - thanks :)